# Spring Boot Data console application

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-data, console-application

I'm gonna create a Java console application for accessesing a database (MySQL). I'm gonna use Spring Boot/Spring Data JPA. What is the correct way to create a console application using Spring Boot?

I found a few ways to do this:

- `spring.main.web-application-type=NONE` (in application.properties)
- `spring.main.web-environment = false` (in application.properties)
- using the Spring Shell project
- implementing the `CommandLineRunner` interface

I suppose that some of them may be obsolete, have pros and cons. Could you please explain how to create a plain console application using Spring Boot/Spring Data?

Comment: What do you mean by console application, that provides for you the result of execution in the logs?

Comment: @Rebai Ahmed I currently have a plain Java application (public static void main(String[] args) {} ). This is a plain console application, text user interface. I need to add Spring Boot/Spring Data to this application somehow.

Answer (score 1):

Recently, I have done a console application, as you require now. I did that by implementing `CommandLineRunner` interface. When spring boot starts the application, it will invoke the `run(String... args)` method of `CommandLineRunner` interface.
So, you can autowire(or using constructor injection) spring data repositories in this implemention class(**e.g.** AppRunner) & invoke database operations.

Instead of MySql database, I have you used MongoDB along with some caching operations.

**Example:**

AppRunner.java

```
package com.cache.caching;

import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import org.springframework.boot.CommandLineRunner;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

@Component
public class AppRunner implements CommandLineRunner {

    Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(AppRunner.class);

    BookRepository bookRepository;

    public AppRunner(BookRepository bookRepository) {
        this.bookRepository = bookRepository;
    }

    @Override
    public void run(String... args) throws Exception {
        logger.info("articles fetching..."+bookRepository.getArticles());
        logger.info("articles fetching..."+bookRepository.getArticles());
        logger.info("articles fetching..."+bookRepository.getArticles());
        logger.info("articles fetching..."+bookRepository.getArticles());
    }
}
```

BookRepository.java

```
package com.cache.caching;


import java.net.UnknownHostException;
import java.util.List;

public interface BookRepository {
    List<Article> getArticles() throws UnknownHostException;
}
```

BookRepositoryImpl.java

```
package com.cache.caching;

import com.mongodb.*;
import org.bson.codecs.pojo.annotations.BsonId;
import org.springframework.cache.annotation.Cacheable;
import org.springframework.data.mongodb.MongoCollectionUtils;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.function.Consumer;

@Component
public class BookRepositoryImpl implements BookRepository{

    @Override
    @Cacheable("articles")
    public List<Article> getArticles() throws UnknownHostException {
       
        MongoClient mongoClient
                = new MongoClient(new MongoClientURI("mongodb://localhost:27017"));
        DB db = mongoClient.getDB("Mart");
        DBCollection collection =  db.getCollection("articles");
        DBCursor cursor = collection.find();
        List<Article> list= new ArrayList<>();
        while (cursor.hasNext()) {
           Article article = new Article();
           DBObject dbObject = cursor.next();
           article.setId((Double) dbObject.get("_id"));
           article.setSubject((String) dbObject.get("subject"));
           list.add(article);
        }
        return list;
    }
    
}
```

In your case, you can provide MySQL database connection details here in application.yml / application.properties file.

**CachingApplication.java** - application starts here, this `SpringApplication.run(CachingApplication.class, args);` invokes the `run(String... args)` method of `CommandLineRunner` interface.

```
package com.cache.caching;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.cache.annotation.EnableCaching;

@SpringBootApplication
@EnableCaching
public class CachingApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(CachingApplication.class, args);
    }

}
```

Sample: [Sample Full Example Here](https://github.com/donthadineshkumar/spring-caching-mongodb-example.git)